# Keep count and append it to a list in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, hashmap

I have a list that looks something like this.

```
data = [
      {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'}
      {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'}
      {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'}
      {'time': 12, 'data': 'dc'}
      {'time': 13, 'data': 'ak'}
      {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'}
```

I need to count the data object which is the same and keep the count of data. I'm expecting an output like this.

```
Expected Output:

data = [
      {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd','count' : 2}
      {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd','count' : 2}
      {'time': 12, 'data': 'dc','count' : 1}
      {'time': 13, 'data': 'ak','count' : 1}
```

Is it possible ? I'm trying to do this in python.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly format your code. This is not valid Python or JSON syntax. What have you tried so far to solve this? Are you familiar with loops in Python? What behaviour do you expect for entries where ``data`` matches but not ``time``, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the way I did it is not very efficient, it is doable by iterating through the dictionaries and checking if values of `time` and `data` keys are the same for counting:

```py
data = [
    {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'},
    {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'},
    {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'},
    {'time': 12, 'data': 'dc'},
    {'time': 13, 'data': 'ak'},
    {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'}
]

data_counted = []
for d in data:
    for d_c in data_counted:
        if d['time'] == d_c['time'] and d['data'] == d_c['data']:
            d_c['count'] += 1
            break
    else:
        d_new = d.copy()
        d_new['count'] = 1
        data_counted.append(d_new)

print(data_counted)
```

```py
[{'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd', 'count': 2}, 
 {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd', 'count': 2}, 
 {'time': 12, 'data': 'dc', 'count': 1}, 
 {'time': 13, 'data': 'ak', 'count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it should get the job done.

```
data = [
      {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'},
      {'time': 10, 'data': 'abcd'},
      {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'},
      {'time': 12, 'data': 'dc'},
      {'time': 13, 'data': 'ak'},
      {'time': 11, 'data': 'bcd'},
]

temp = {}

for i in data:
    s = "{}-{}".format(i['time'], i['data'])
    i['count'] = 1

    if (s not in temp.keys()):
        temp[s] = i
    else:
        temp[s]['count'] += 1

data = [temp[i] for i in temp.keys()]

print(data)
```

```
[{'count': 2, 'data': 'abcd', 'time': 10}, 
{'count': 2, 'data': 'bcd', 'time': 11}, 
{'count': 1, 'data': 'dc', 'time': 12}, 
{'count': 1, 'data': 'ak', 'time': 13}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the dictionaries having the same `data` value:

```
from itertools import groupby

def keyFunc(d):
    return d['data']

def merge(*dicts):
    return {**dicts[0], 'count': len(dicts)}

merged = [merge(*g) for i, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=keyFunc), key=keyFunc)]
print(merged)
```

This resulting `merged` dict will be:

```
[
 {'count': 2, 'data': 'abcd', 'time': 10},
 {'count': 1, 'data': 'ak', 'time': 13},
 {'count': 2, 'data': 'bcd', 'time': 11},
 {'count': 1, 'data': 'dc', 'time': 12}
]
```